# stb_image.h in Visual Studio - unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I've downloaded stb_image.h (https://github.com/nothings/stb) and included in the .cpp file I want to use it.

Then I use the function to load an image

```
image_data = stbi_load(fileNames[i], &image_width, &image_height, &image_pixel_components, 0);
```

When I try to run the code in Visual Studio I get an error:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _stbi_load referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall CubemapTexture::Load(void)" (?Load@CubemapTexture@@QAE_NXZ)    ...\CubemapTexture.obj

Error   40  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _stbi_load    ...\Texture.obj
```

Answer (score 25):

The answer is right at the top of [stb_image.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h):

> Do this:
>
> ```
>   #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
> ```
>
> before you include this file in *one* C or C++ file to create the implementation.
> i.e. it should look like this:
>
> ```
> #include ....
> #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION    
> #include "stb_image.h"
> ```

Without this define, you will get errors about unresolved external symbols.